# Kubernetes Istio Gateway & VirtualService Config Flask Example

Tags: flask, kubernetes, devops

I try to get some hands on experience with K8s & istio. I am using minikube and I try to deploy a dummy flask web-app. However, for some reason I do not manage to get the istio routing working.

E.g.

```
curl -v -H 'Host: hello.com' 'http://127.0.0.1/' --> 503 Service Unavailable
```

Do you see any issue in my specs?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: flask-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "hello.com" 

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: flaskvirtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "hello.com" 
  gateways:
  - flask-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: flask.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask
  labels:
    app: flask
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask
        image: digitalocean/flask-helloworld
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: flask
  ports:
  - name: name-of-service-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
```

Thanks for your support here!

Cheers

EDIT:

here the updated service definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask
  labels:
    app: flask
    service: flask
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    name: http
  selector:
    app: flask
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look at this sample from the istio repo:

https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/samples/helloworld

This `helloworld` app is a flask app and you can find the python source code in `src`

---

#### Syntax

In your yaml you do not have `---` between your `Gateway` and `VirtualService`.

#### DNS

You also don't make mention of `DNS` IE you need to make sure that the box you are running `curl` on has the ability to resolve your domain `hello.com` to the istio service ip. Since you are using minikube you could add an entry to your OS hosts file.

#### Routability

It has the ability to send requests to it, IE if you are outside the cluster you need an external ip or do something with `kubectl port-forward ...`

I hope this helps you sort things out!

Comment: Thanks, the like you shared and you comment helped me to get make it work.

I simply updated my service definition

And added the ```---```that I forgot and all works

Comment: Awesome, glad it all worked out.